# Friedman's test manual calculation

Tags: r, statistics, calculation

I have obtained a negative value from the Friedman's test. The data is:

```
        Full    MIC     ReliefF LCorrel InfoGain
equinox 69.939  80.178  78.794  75.205  62.268
lucene  78.175  84.103  79.017  82.044  75.564
mylyn   75.531  78.006  77.161  47.711  81.575
pde     70.282  82.686  81.884  75.07   79.476
jdt     71.675  93.202  95.387  85.878  82.818
```

Ranking is below

```
        Full    MIC     ReliefF LCorrel InfoGain
equinox 2       5       4       3       1
lucene  2       5       3       4       1
mylyn   2       4       3       1       5
pde     1       5       4       2       3
jdt     1       4       5       3       2
Sum     8      23      19      13      12
```

The Friedman's F Calculation formula:

```
F = (5/[5*5*(5+1)] * [8*8 + 23*23 + 19*19 + 13*13 + 12*12] - [5*5*(5+1)]
```

The value I get is `-107.7666667`.

How do I interpret that? The examples I have seen all have positive result.

**I know about the R code but want the manual calculation.**

Comment: Try `abs` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I generated the results and it worked

```
pacc_part
f1 <- friedman.test(pacc_part) 
print (f1) 
# Post-hoc tests are conducted only if omnimus Kruskal-Wallis test p-value 
is 0.05 or less. 
if ( f1$p.value < 0.05 ) 
{ 

n1 <- posthoc.friedman.nemenyi.test(pacc_part) 
} 
n1; 
# alternate representation of post-hoc test results 
summary(n1);
```